# Can we integrate Python Robot framework with SDN/NFV and Cloud integration?

Tags: python, cloud, robotframework, sdn

Hi we are going to use Robot framework for our device automation testing. Further to proceed we are planning to integrate SDN/NFV and Cloud components into Python RIDE. Will Robot framework supports the integration.

Comment: The better question is, can you integrate SDN/NFV and cloud components with python. If you can do it in python, you can do it in robot framework. RIDE has nothing to do with it, it's just an IDE.

Comment: Thanks  @Bryan Oakley  for your comments.